# Detect if element has padding using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How could I detect if an element has padding applied to it?

So something like:

```
if($('div.MiddleColumn') has padding of 5px) {
do something
}
else
{
do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the total horizontal padding of your element :

```
var hz_padding = $("el").innerWidth() - $("el").width();
```

`.innerWidth()` returns the same value as `.width()`, **plus the padding**. So `hz_padding` will be > 0 if `$("el")` has any padding.

The interesting thing here is that you will have the **computed** styles, which might be different from those in the stylesheet.

More on [.innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) and [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Use `.outerWidth()` if you want to include borders, and `.outerWidth(true)` to include margin.

And there are obviousy the same methods for the height.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasPadding = false,
    element = $('div.MiddleColumn');

$.each(['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'], function(i, side) {
   if (parseInt(element.css('padding-' + side))) {
       hasPadding = true;
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
if($('div.MiddleColumn').css('padding') == "5px") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if($('div.MiddleColumn').css("padding") == "5px")
{
    /*
      do something
    */
}
else 
{
    /*
      do something else
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) method

```
if ( $('div.MiddleColumn').css('padding-left') === '5px' ) {
   do something
}
else {
   do something else
}
```